# join without common columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables
the first one consists of id (int) and end_date (datetime)

| id | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.01.2023. 7:50 |
| 2 | 12.01.2023 8:40 |
| 3 | 12.01.2023 13:15 |
| 4 | 12.01.2023 18:03 |

the second consists of only start_date (datetime)

| start_date |
| --- |
| 12.01.2023. 7:45 |
| 12.01.2023 8:15 |
| 12.01.2023 11:10 |
| 12.01.2023 12:32 |

I need to compare start_date to each id in the table one

so the output will be

| id | end_date | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.01.2023. 7:50 | 12.01.2023. 7:45 |
| 2 | 12.01.2023 8:40 | 12.01.2023 8:15 |
| 3 | 12.01.2023 13:15 | 12.01.2023 11:10 |
| 4 | 12.01.2023 18:03 | 12.01.2023 12:32 |

I tried to do in with row_number function but it doesn't work correctly (when in one table will be an empty date for example or different number of strings)

```
select id, end_date, start_date  from (select id, end_date, row_number() over (order by end_date) date_order from table1) b
left join 
(select start_date, row_number() over (order by start_date) date_order from table2) a
on a.date_order = b.date_order
```

Comment: What is the exact output you want here?

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms you're using. (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Column data type? (Those _dates_ look weird.)

Comment: And show us your current SQL attempt.

Comment: How do you pair the rows from the tables? What's the expected result if there are different number of rows, or completely different date-time values? E.g. add `12.12.2022 7:45` to table 2, and adjust the result accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If the window function `row_number()` is supported by your RDBMS, and assuming the order of records on table2 needs to match those in table1:

```
select t1.*, t2.start_date
from table1 t1
inner join (
  select row_number() over (order by start_date) as id, start_date
  from table2
) as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: I suppose this will work fine for the 4 row sample tables, but the problem is probably more complex.

Comment: Correct, the OP should add more details if not the case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your start and end dates are of DATE datatype or they could be converted to DATE datatypes you could try to "join" your tables by comparing differences between dates.

```sql
WITH      S a m p l e    D a t a :
    ends (ID, END_DATE) As
        ( Select 1, To_Date('12.01.2023 07:50', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24_mi') From Dual Union All
          Select 2, To_Date('12.01.2023 08:40', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24_mi') From Dual Union All
          Select 3, To_Date('12.01.2023 13:15', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24_mi') From Dual Union All
          Select 4, To_Date('12.01.2023 18:03', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24_mi') From Dual 
        ),
    starts (START_DATE) As
        ( Select To_Date('12.01.2023 07:45', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24_mi') From Dual Union All
          Select To_Date('12.01.2023 08:15', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24_mi') From Dual Union All
          Select To_Date('12.01.2023 11:10', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24_mi') From Dual Union All
          Select To_Date('12.01.2023 12:32', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24_mi') From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--       M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT  ID, To_Char(Min(START_DATE), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') "START_DATE_STR", To_Char(END_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') "END_DATE_STR"
FROM
(
Select  ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By CASE WHEN e.END_DATE > s.START_DATE Then s.START_DATE End Order By (END_DATE - START_DATE) ) "RN_START",
        e.ID, e.END_DATE, s.START_DATE,
        Min(END_DATE - START_DATE) Over(Partition By e.ID, e.END_DATE) "MIN_DIFF"
From    starts s
Inner Join ends e ON(e.END_DATE > s.START_DATE)
Order By ID, END_DATE, START_DATE
)
WHERE RN_START = 1 OR END_DATE - START_DATE = MIN_DIFF
GROUP BY ID, END_DATE
ORDER BY ID
```

```sql
/*     R e s u l t :
        ID START_DATE_STR   END_DATE_STR    
---------- ---------------- ----------------
         1 12.01.2023 07:45 12.01.2023 07:50
         2 12.01.2023 08:15 12.01.2023 08:40
         3 12.01.2023 11:10 12.01.2023 13:15
         4 12.01.2023 12:32 12.01.2023 18:03    */
```

NOTE:
In case of different number of records in these tables this wil produce either duplicate start date or ID will not be present depending on if there are start dates smaler than end dates and on how many start dates are smaller than particular end date. Test it and see if it helps.
Example: if there were no third row in Start Dates table The result would be:

```sql
/*
        ID START_DATE_STR   END_DATE_STR    
---------- ---------------- ----------------
         1 12.01.2023 07:45 12.01.2023 07:50
         2 12.01.2023 08:15 12.01.2023 08:40
         3 12.01.2023 12:32 12.01.2023 13:15
         4 12.01.2023 12:32 12.01.2023 18:03   */
```

... it would join start 12:32 to both remaining end dates that are bigger---

Answer (score -1):

you can use anti-join without mutual column

```
-- Example tables
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    column1 INT,
    column2 VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    column3 VARCHAR(10),
    column4 INT
);

-- Insert some sample data into the tables
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (2, 'X2'), (3, 'X3'), (4, 'X4');

-- Perform an anti-join without a mutual column
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON 1 = 1  -- Dummy condition to make it a Cartesian product
```

and result looks like this... which contains all combinations of columns.

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 | A       | 2       | X2      |
|       1 | A       | 3       | X3      |
|       1 | A       | 4       | X4      |
|       2 | B       | 2       | X2      |
|       2 | B       | 3       | X3      |
|       2 | B       | 4       | X4      |
|       3 | C       | 2       | X2      |
|       3 | C       | 3       | X3      |
|       3 | C       | 4       | X4      |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: That doesn't look like OP's desired result at all. Op wants a 4 rows result set, but would get 16 rows.

Comment: when I have writen this answer, OP didnt have any desired output or what he/she attempted, it was just written about datasets and general idea to compare, this post has been edited after my answer